# Node.js native extensions on Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, node.js

I compiled the version v0.5.9 of node.js (I know, is unstable) using Visual Studio 2010 and I obtained node.exe to Windows 7. Now, I wrote the Hello World example (https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/aug/23/writing-nodejs-native-extensions/) of the native extension use the same VS 2010 compiler on a dll file. Then, How I can "link" this dll with the node.exe? I know that in linux, the node-waf building tool is used but I don't know what I have to use to link them on Windows.

In my implementation, I can't use **Cygwin** or **linux**...is under Windows.

p.d.: I'm trying to create an OpenGL engine based on offscreen rendering (not WebGL)

Comment: [node-webgl](https://github.com/creationix/node-webgl). Looks like it supports windows, it's basically a webgl API based wrapper on opengl

Comment: @raynos Well, I cannot use webgl because the data is huge..I need to render data up to 1 Gb and no client requirement about the video card. thanks

Comment: node-webgl is a library that allows you to talk to opengl on the server. It just happens to have a webgl like API for code portability

Comment: why do you say you can't use cygwin on windows?

Comment: I started creating [node-opengl](https://github.com/hross/node-opengl) because I wanted SDL/OpenGL specific bindings if you are interested in that.

Comment: @Raynos Well, Webgl is my last option! I have several lines of code on OGL working fine. Thanks

Comment: @Nickolay Well, I'm using the visual studio compiler to do that..using cygwin I have to use g++.

Comment: @hross thanks, let me try it..and I notify you..particulary, I prefer GLUT or FreeGLUT but SDL is a good option. Thanks again